# Generic DAO - "Never go full generic!"

Tags: spring, hibernate, dao, hibernate-generic-dao

Ive seen allot of usages of generic dao over the internet.
you gotta love it:

```
public interface GenericDao <T, PK extends Serializable> {}

public class GenericDaoHibernateImpl <T, PK extends Serializable>
implements GenericDao<T, PK>
```

a new class appeared? no problem:

```
public interface NewClassDao extends GenericDao<NewClass, Long>
```

and we're all set.

now, 
how bad is it if i go "full-generic" and do something like:

```
public interface FullGenericDao 

public class FullGenericDaoHibernateImpl
```

now i can only use one DAO (of Object with casting!)

a new class appeared again? 
no problem:

```
NewClassApperedAgain newClassAppeared = (NewClassApperedAgain) FullGenericDao.getItemById(20, NewClassApperedAgain.class);
```

two questions comes to mind:

1) Is it even possible to go "full-generic" and actually create such a DAO? I mean i dont see why not passing for every method of the dao the className and just do the casting neccessary?
save(object,className);
delete(object,className); etc..

2) What are the Cons (i'm sure there are) of such practice?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

DAO objects are there to contain domain model specific logic connected with persistence layer.

You can go *full generic*, but then you have to face questions like:

- Where should I put the logic connected with searching (e.g. constructing WHERE clause)?

  - `User findUserByOrganizationId(Serializable organizationId)`
- Where do I put some specific mapping functions (e.g. aggregate queries)?

  - `Map<Organization, Integer> findUserCountPerOrganization()`

I am pretty sure there are other architectural / logical issues. Also the generics will be erased during the runtime so you have introduced the necessity to include domain object `Class<?>` in every method signature.

*TL;DR* it is possible to "go full generic", but you will need to move non-shared persistence logic to the higher levels. It is better to do the shared generic logic in some `AbstractDaoImpl` and then subclass that. You might end up with empty implementations (the generic superclass might have all you need), but you will have place for future domain model specific methods.